# Can't change css class using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Settings</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/common.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/settings.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/buttons.css">
    <script src="scripts/utils.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var language = localStorage.getItem("idioma");
            $(language).removeClass("shiny-btn").addClass("shiny-btn clicked");
       });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="settingsPanel">Settings</div>
    <a id="spanish" class="shiny-btn" onclick="setLanguage('spanish');">Spanish</a>
    <a id="catalan" class="shiny-btn" onclick="setLanguage('catalan');">Catalan</a>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is buttons.css file:

```
.shiny-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align:center;
    width: 15em;
    padding: .5em;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    border: solid thin #882d13;
    -webkit-border-radius: .7em;
    -moz-border-radius: .7em;
    border-radius: .7em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999; 
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #bbb;
    background-color: #ce401c;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#e9ede8), to(#ce401c),color-stop(0.4, #8c1b0b));
}

.shiny-btn.clicked {
    background-color:gray;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) inset;
}
```

I'm sure I have a value in `var language`.
But when I do this: `$(language).removeClass("shiny-btn").addClass("shiny-btn clicked");` nothing changes.

Do you know why?

Comment: ur css declaration is wrong what means by `.shiny-btn.clicked {`

Comment: Have you tried addClass("shiny-btn").addClass("clicked") ?

Comment: console.log(language) - after you have defined it to see if it is really set to what you think it is.

Comment: @Decad: I'm getting a 'spanish'.

Comment: don't you just want to add class `clicked` but not remove `shiny-btn`?

Comment: The issue is with your CSS, the other answers should resolve this issue.

Comment: @vanasFannel, please accept an answer :) so that we can go further :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first u change in **CSS** ( not necessary )

```
.clicked {
    background-color:gray;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) inset;
}
```

then try with this

```
$('a').live ('click hover mouseover', function() {
    var lang = $(this).id;
    $('#'+lang).addClass("clicked");
 },
   function() {  
    $(this).removeClass("clicked");
});
```

see **[here](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)** clearly mentioned:

> It's important to note that this
>   method does not replace a class. It
>   simply adds the class, appending it to
>   any which may already be assigned to
>   the elements.

Comment: His CSS is perfectly fine. Read up: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html. This part especially:

'The following rule matches any P element whose class attribute has been assigned a list of whitespace-separated values that includes both pastoral and marine:

p.pastoral.marine { color: green }'

Comment: No need to change the CSS if the OP wants the style to apply only to `shiny-btn`s that are also `clicked`.  Perhaps there are other types of `clicked` buttons that should be styled differently.

Comment: The correct answer is change my code with this line: `$('#'+lang).addClass("clicked");`. Thank you very much.

Comment: @rciq i agree with u, but then how will he add that class via `jQuery`; that method is useful with DOM loaded

Comment: @diEcho: He will add it just normally by .addClass("clicked") and that's it. No CSS changes needed.

Answer (score 2):

use just $(language).addClass("clicked")

Answer (score 1):

```
.shiny-btn.clicked { ... }
```

this represents 2 classes, `shiny-btn` and `clicked` so, you will need to have

```
<html_element class="shiny-btn">
    <html_element class="clicked"> ... </html_element>
</html_element>
```

what you probably want is to **inherit** all the previous class and override with the class `clicked`

```
.shiny-btn {        
    /* default properties */
}

.clicked {
    background-color:gray;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) inset;
}

.selected {
    /* add here your selected style */
 }
```

and then, just use:

```
// make a fancy hover on buttons
$(".shiny-btn").hover( 
    function() {  // on mouseover
        $(this).addClass("clicked");
    }, 
    function() {  // on mouseout
        $(this).removeClass("clicked");
    });

// add .selected class to the correct language
$("#" + language).addClass("selected");
```

Comment: This CSS: '.classA.classB {}' will match '<div class="classA classB"/>'. Read up: Read up: http://w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html. This part especially: 'The following rule matches any P element whose class attribute has been assigned a list of whitespace-separated values that includes both pastoral and marine: p.pastoral.marine { color: green }

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you only need to add the 'clicked' class. jQuery should handle it well:

```
$("#"+language).addClass("clicked");
```

Edit: As diEcho pointed out, language is apparently a string. So an ID selector is required.

Comment: your are wrong still. `language` only contain id name you must be add  `$('#'+language).`  btw when there are already multiple answer then why u copy them ?? is that different from others??

Comment: Firstly, the author didn't specify what the var language contains exactly. From his code I assumed it's already a html element or a jQuery. Secondly, I didn't copy your answer because it's incorrect and at the time I was posting I could not see any others.

Comment: now u can see; so what abt deleting ur answer coz it's still incorrect

Comment: Edit: you are right. I missed a line in his code. I will edit the answer now:)